# PYTHONHOME environment variable is unset and empty, I don't know what put to have my python related command working again on linux

Tags: python, mercurial, centos7

I am software developer, I have started working on Centos 7. I use mercurial(hg) for code versioning. Suddenly the mercurial commands and all other python related commands have started giving this output error message:

```
`
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site`
```

I understand that I need to set Python home again. But I don't really know what to put here. export PYTHONHOME=  ?
I typed  `whereis python` and I ve got this:

```
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python3.6 /etc/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Then I tried to update PYTHONHOME with all those, then then /usr/bin/python3 only gave me this reduce message :  `ImportError: No module named site` . But still I cannot use python related commands.
I also have the error when I try reinstall the python(yum install).

Any clue on this issue please?
Thank you in adavance

Comment: I suspect Python isn't installed correctly (or you accidentally removed part of a working installation). Ordinarily, you shouldn't need to set `PYTHONHOME` without knowing *why* you need to set it.

Comment: I have new inputs @chepner

I have installed a custom RPM which in include another python2.7(deposited on /usr/lib64/python2.7. Its had added/delete python files. The last time I was able to use yum update I noticed python file conflict at the end.  I Remove the rpm, I am able to use yum command, but still don't how to recover my python

Comment: You will likely need to reinstall it using your OS's upstream repository. When you installed the other RPM, it "took" ownership of some files from the original Python RPM, and when you removed it, those files were deleted, because the YUM database didn't know they originally belonged to the original Python RPM. You'll have to reinstall that package, presumably from your OS's upstream repository.

Comment: @Chepner you are all right. I just copied a python2.7 form another computer(same hard/soft)  and it is working again. Thank you for your help!!